# Batch script to find a string in a messy file and loop until all strings found

Tags: command-line, batch

First post here so please be gentle. I am trying to find a string which is at the end of a URL in a messy file that contains all kinds of formatting stuff like `\n\t\t\t<p>` which makes finding the correct `delims` tricky.

My data file looks exactly like this:

```
href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19950_en_1\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Wolf Resting image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19641_en_1\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19975_en_1\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Japanese Fox image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19091_en_1\">Get Clown Fish image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19044_en_1\">Get Buzzing Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19245_en_1\">Get Flamingo image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19042_en_1\">Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19064_en_1\">Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19188_en_1\">Get Dragonfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19449_en_1\">Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19645_en_1\">Get Puppy with a Leaf image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19688_en_1\">Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19273_en_1\">Get Fuzzy Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p>
```

Here is my code:

```
for /F "tokens=16 delims=asset-blobs/" %%a in ('findstr /I "https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/" mydata.txt') do set "imageid=%%aen_1"  
echo Image ID is: %imageid%
```

What I am after is the string at the end of the URL after **asset-blobs/** for example **19950_en_1** from the first match and **19641_en_1** from the second, and so on.

My problems:

1. The `for` loop does not loop.
2. I am not capturing a clean string so I have to append *en_1* to the string after I find it. This part is no big deal I can live with it.

When I run the batch file I get only 1 (the first) match and it stops.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. I don't want to use VBscript or anything else, just native Windows commands if possible.

I'm a total newb to scripting but I am trying to learn. Thank you.

Comment: I notice an answerer mentions to see "delayed expansion". If that's your issue then bear in mind that Batch scripting can be absolutely ridiculous, and that's a case of it. As an example, do `set /?` and see from where it says "Delayed environment variable expansion is useful...".  Third party scripting language would be a better option!

Comment: Insisting on batch is perverse, the more so because this task is nearly impossible in batch and easy in VBScript, or any scripting language, such as Perl, Python, etc.. In VBS you could, in a loop, use INSTR to find the first occurrence of "asset_blobs/". The next characters up to "\" are your first result. Truncate the string to now start one character later than the "\". Repeat. Exit when there are no more left (INSTR returns 0 for "asset_blobs/"). You are like a surgeon saying "I want to do a heart operation, but with a spoon instead of a scalpel.". VBS is "native Windows" anyhow.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for explaining. Like I said I'm new to scripting so this stubbornness is part of me learning "why" batch sucks first-hand instead of just because someone tells me it sucks. I appreciate your patience. Now I am convinced batch will not do the job. I am trying to do this in PowerShell and hope it's more robust than Batch.

Comment: Unless you are tasked with maintaining legacy systems, batch is obsolete, yet many cling to it because it is familiar. Many ask for batch simply because they think it is synonymous with scipting or automation,  not realizing that PowerShell is now the preferred method of Windows administration & automation. Big picture: It's sad to see people struggle with archaic & cryptic batch files when PowerShell is damn-near self-documenting.

Comment: And, speaking as a life-long geek, PowerShell is more fun! I was never big on batch, but did my share of .vbs automation. Many things that were out-of-reach in .vbs are accessible in PowerShell (APIs)

Comment: Point being, PowerShell is so simple and fun without extreme complexities. Once you try and see the power of object oriented with PS, you'll want to use it all over the place.

Comment: @PImpJuice:v See my one-liner answer below. It's others that are needlessly complex.

Answer (score 1):

- **Update**

**[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** can do it using a line and you don't need to escape any special characters in batch file:

```batch-file
(Get-Content "G:\data\file.txt").split("/\") | Select-String '^[0-9]'
```

- Or using aliases **`Get-Content == gc`** and : **`Select-String == sls`**

```batch-file
(gc "G:\data\file.txt").split("\/")|sls '^[0-9]'

# or... 
(gc "G:\data\file.txt").split("/\")|sls '^[0-9]'
```

> - Just save as file.bat and run this hybrid file **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**/**[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** code:

```batch-file
@echo off

(findstr /b .g "%~f0"|Powershell -c - ) >"%tmp%\ps_outs.txt"
type "%tmp%\ps_outs.txt" & goto :EOF

(gc "G:\data\file.txt").split("\/")|sls '^[0-9]'
```

- Or...

```batch-file
@echo off

(findstr /b .g "%~f0"|Powershell -c - ) & type "G:\data\ps_outs.txt" & goto :EOF
(gc "G:\data\file.txt").split("/\")|sls '^[0-9]'|Out-File -FilePath "G:\data\ps_outs.txt"
```

- Output:

```batch-file
19950_en_1
19641_en_1
19975_en_1
19091_en_1
19044_en_1
19245_en_1
19042_en_1
19064_en_1
19188_en_1
19449_en_1
19645_en_1
19688_en_1
19273_en_1
```

Update **[`/end`](https://superuser.com/questions/1537916/batch-script-to-find-a-string-in-a-messy-file-and-loop-until-all-strings-found/1540584#1540584)**

---

- **If using a batch with PowerShell is acceptable try, so give a try...**

```batch-file
;   @echo off
;   
;   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
;   set "_out_puts=%temp%\!randon!_list_line_out.txt"
;   cd.>nul>"!_out_puts!" && cd.>nul>"%temp%\string_temp_list.log"
;   
;   for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('2^>nul "%windir%\system32\where.exe" /r "%windir%" "powershell.exe"
;   ')do >>"%temp%\string_temp_list.log" ("%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" -rbv ; "%~dpnx0"|"%%~dpnxi" -c - ) && goto :continue
        $_lines = Get-content "G:\this folder\data\mydata.txt";
        $_lines.Replace('\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"',' \').Replace('asset-blobs/',"""`r`n""").Replace('</a>','\\').Replace('\">',' ').Replace('\\',' ').Replace('"','').Replace("_?"," ").Replace(' \ ',' ')|Out-String|scb;Get-Clipboard
;      
;   :continue
;   for /f tokens^=1delims^=^< %%i in ('
;   type "%temp%\string_temp_list.log"^|"%windir%\system32\findstr.exe" /rb [0-9]*\_[a-z]*
;   ')do echo/%%~i && set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_str_!_cnt!=%%~i"
;    
;   for /l %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do call echo/id: !_str_%%L:~0,10!  name: !_str_%%L:~10!>>"!_out_puts!"
;   type "!_out_puts!"|C:\Windows\System32\clip.exe 
;   
;   echo\ & echo\Image lines strings variables: _str_1 to _str_!_cnt! 
;   echo\Images listed in outputs on file: "!_out_puts!" & endlocal
;   "%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" -1 & goto :eof
```

- **File content:**

  - The first two of the file and the last two, tested with 9 lines in this layout

```batch-file
\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19950_en_1\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Wolf Resting image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19641_en_1\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19975_en_1\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Japanese Fox image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19091_en_1\">Get Clown Fish image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19044_en_1\">Get Buzzing Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19245_en_1\">Get Flamingo image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19042_en_1\">Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19064_en_1\">Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19188_en_1\">Get Dragonfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19449_en_1\">Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19645_en_1\">Get Puppy with a Leaf image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19688_en_1\">Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19273_en_1\">Get Fuzzy Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p>
\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19951_en_2\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Wolf Resting image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19641_en_2\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19975_en_2\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Japanese Fox image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19091_en_2\">Get Clown Fish image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19044_en_2\">Get Buzzing Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19245_en_2\">Get Flamingo image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19042_en_2\">Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19064_en_2\">Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19188_en_2\">Get Dragonfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19449_en_2\">Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19645_en_1\">Get Puppy with a Leaf image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19688_en_2\">Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19273_en_2\">Get Fuzzy Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p>
....
\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19956_en_7\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Wolf Resting image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19641_en_7\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19975_en_7\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Japanese Fox image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19091_en_7\">Get Clown Fish image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19044_en_7\">Get Buzzing Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19245_en_7\">Get Flamingo image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19042_en_7\">Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19064_en_7\">Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19188_en_7\">Get Dragonfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19449_en_7\">Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19645_en_1\">Get Puppy with a Leaf image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19688_en_7\">Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19273_en_7\">Get Fuzzy Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p>
\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19957_en_8\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Wolf Resting image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19641_en_8\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a data-content-id=\"\" data-content-type=\"\" href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19975_en_8\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"\">Get Japanese Fox image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19091_en_8\">Get Clown Fish image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19044_en_8\">Get Buzzing Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19245_en_8\">Get Flamingo image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19042_en_8\">Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19064_en_8\">Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19188_en_8\">Get Dragonfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19449_en_8\">Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19645_en_1\">Get Puppy with a Leaf image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19688_en_8\">Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p><a href=\"https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/asset-blobs/19273_en_8\">Get Fuzzy Bee image</a></p>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td>\n\t\t\t<p>
```

- **Outputs:**

```batch-file
19950_en_1 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_1 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_1 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_1 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_1 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_1 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_1 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_1 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_1 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_1 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_1 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_1 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19951_en_2 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_2 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_2 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_2 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_2 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_2 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_2 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_2 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_2 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_2 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_2 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_2 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19952_en_3 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_3 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_3 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_3 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_3 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_3 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_3 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_3 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_3 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_3 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_3 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_3 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19953_en_4 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_4 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_4 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_4 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_4 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_4 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_4 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_4 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_4 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_4 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_4 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_4 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19953_en_4 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_4 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_4 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_4 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_4 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_4 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_4 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_4 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_4 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_4 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_4 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_4 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19954_en_5 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_5 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_5 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_5 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_5 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_5 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_5 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_5 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_5 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_5 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_5 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_5 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19955_en_6 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_6 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_6 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_6 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_6 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_6 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_6 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_6 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_6 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_6 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_6 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_6 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19956_en_7 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_7 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_7 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_7 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_7 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_7 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_7 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_7 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_7 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_7 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_7 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_7 Get Fuzzy Bee image
19957_en_8 Get Wolf Resting image
19641_en_8 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image
19975_en_8 Get Japanese Fox image
19091_en_8 Get Clown Fish image
19044_en_8 Get Buzzing Bee image
19245_en_8 Get Flamingo image
19042_en_8 Get Butterfly in Yellow Flowers image
19064_en_8 Get Cattle Under Stormy Sky image
19188_en_8 Get Dragonfly image
19449_en_8 Get Ladybug on Flower Petal image
19645_en_1 Get Puppy with a Leaf image
19688_en_8 Get Red Lacewing Butterfly image
19273_en_8 Get Fuzzy Bee image

Image lines strings variables: _str_1 to _str_117                                       
Images listed in outputs on file: "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\_list_line_out.txt"

Press any key to continue...
```

---

**1)** Use a hybrid batch with PowerShell delimiting all lines starting with **`;`** to use the batch session and a normal one to be used by PowerShell:

```batch-file
;   echo/ line/code Batch Session
    write-host line/code PowerShell Session
```

**2)** Set environment scenario and all variable you will need need for this process:

```batch-file
;   @echo off
;   
;   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
;   set "_out_puts=%temp%\!randon!_list_line_out.txt"
;   cd.>nul>"!_out_puts!" && cd.>nul>"%temp%\string_temp_list.log"
```

**3)** Implement a **`for`** loop to filter in the **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)** itself, all lines that do not start with **`;`** and that will be redirected at runtime to **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** (two lines in this case), where they will be executed, and when finished go to label :continue...

```batch-file
;   for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('2^>nul "%windir%\system32\where.exe" /r "%windir%" "powershell.exe"
;   ')do >>"%temp%\string_temp_list.log" ("%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" -rbv ; "%~dpnx0"|"%%~dpnxi" -c - ) && goto :continue

        $_lines = Get-content "G:\this folder\data\mydata.txt";
        $_lines.Replace('\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"',' \').Replace('asset-blobs/',"""`r`n""").Replace('</a>','\\').Replace('\">',' ').Replace('\\',' ').Replace('"','').Replace("_?"," ").Replace(' \ ',' ')|Out-String|scb;Get-Clipboard

;   :continue
```

**4)** Two PowerShell lines in item **3** will define/manipulate your long variable on the 1st line, but the second will replace/remove some strings and some characters/strings, in order to make it more readable by transforming into similar lines, where it is possible to apply a regex line per line to extract some filtered strings in a **for** loop, resulting in more or less like this:

```batch-file
\https://kbdevstorage1.plot.core.candles.net/
19950_en_1 Get Wolf Resting image<+ ... varuius charater..../
19641_en_2 Get Provence Chalk-hill Blue Butterfly image<+ ... varuius charater..../
19975_en_8 Get Japanese Fox image<+ several more characters..../
19091_en_9 Get Clown Fish image<+ several more characters..../
19044_en_0 Get Buzzing Bee image<+ several more characters..../
```

**5)** Use the for loop to extract all characters up to **`<`** on each line where it starts with: **`[0-9]*_[a-z]*_`**, with an increment set to save each line in a variable: **`!_str_cnt!++`**

```batch-file
;   for /f tokens^=1delims^=^< %%i in ('
;   type "%temp%\string_temp_list.log"^|"%windir%\system32\findstr.exe" /rb [0-9]*\_[a-z]*
;   ')do echo/%%~i && set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_str_!_cnt!=%%~i"
```

**6)** Just a code example showing how to use the **`!_str_cnt!++`** incrementable  variable to retrieve a value/line in the **`For /L`** loop.

- **Obs.:** This will also place a copy of the entire **`!_Out_puts!`** file contained in your **<kbd>[`Crtl+C`](https://ss64.com/ps/set-clipboard.html)</kbd>** (ClipBoard), paste where you need, if necessary, just a suggestion, very useful wend i coding/testing this script, if dont need it, just remove...

```batch-file
;   for /l %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do echo/!_str_%%L!>>"!_out_puts!"
;   type "!_out_puts!"|C:\Windows\System32\clip.exe
```

**7)** Finally, some information about the result of the work/process ... and a time limit, if you don't need cut too.

```batch-file
;   echo\ & echo\Image lines strings variables: _str_1 to _str_!_cnt! 
;   echo\Images listed in outputs on file: "!_out_puts!" & endlocal & goto :EOF
;   "%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" -1
```

---

- **PowerShell lines:**

```batch-file
$_lines = Get-content "G:\this folder\data\mydata.txt";
$_lines.Replace('\" managed-link=\"\" target=\"',' \').Replace('asset-blobs/',"""`r`n""").Replace('</a>','\\').Replace('\">',' ').Replace('\\',' ').Replace('"','').Replace("_?"," ").Replace(' \ ',' ')|Out-String|scb;Get-Clipboard
```

- Note: You need set the full path to your file **`mydata.txt`**

```batch-file
$_lines = Get-content "G:\Full\Path\To\Your\Data\File\MyData.txt"
```

---

[image]

---

Based/inspired by information from:

- Hybrid Bat-PS1: From **[Walid2me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540014/walid2mi)** **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6076588/8177207)**
- Relace Strings: From **[Sam Boutros](https://powershell.org/profile/Sam-Boutros)** **[answer](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/replacing-multiple-characters-words-etc-in-a-variable/)**
- Escaping Characters in PowersShell: From **[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)** **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46749030/8177207)**

Read more:

- **[Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)**
- **[Slect-String | slc](https://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html)**
- **[Get-Content | gc | cat](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)**
- **[Set-Clipboard](https://ss64.com/ps/set-clipboard.html)**
- **[Get-Clipboard](https://ss64.com/ps/get-clipboard.html)**
- **[EOL End Of Line](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-set-eol.html)**
- **[Line Break: LF, CR and CRLR](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/string-with-escaped-carriage-returnsline-breaks-displays-literally/)**

<sub>- I'm sorry for my limited English...</sub>

Comment: @KeithMiller Calm down my friend, did you see that part in the question? . ***I don't want to use VBscript or anything else, just native Windows commands if possible.***

Comment: Lighten up! I'm just passionate about accurate information. Have you not noticed that PowerShell is now the default console in Power User menu? It is only in your own head that "PowerShell is not native to Windows". It is & will be long after cmd.exe and batch and .vbs have disappeared from the ever-evolving Windows 10.

Comment: @KeithMiller zOk, thank you.. But, what the Windows version this user have?

Comment: Not sure, but PS was optional on XP & installed by default from Win7 onward.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, the **PowerShell** solution would be:

```
$data = Get-Content 'c:\folder\capture.txt'
($data -split 'asset-blobs/').substring(0,10)
```

Output

```
PS C:\...\keith>($data -split 'asset-blobs/').substring(0,10)
href=\"htt
19950_en_1
19641_en_1
19975_en_1
19091_en_1
19044_en_1
19245_en_1
19042_en_1
19064_en_1
19188_en_1
19449_en_1
19645_en_1
19688_en_1
19273_en_1
```

To eliminate the first element & return only the leading digits, we can use:

```
($data -split 'asset-blobs/').ForEach({ If ( $_ -match '(^\d+)') { $Matches[0] }})
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> ($data -split 'asset-blobs/').ForEach({ If ( $_ -match '(^\d+)') { $Matches[0] }})
19950
19641
19975
19091
19044
19245
19042
19064
19188
19449
19645
19688
19273
```

Comment: But why not take the OP at his word: "...the string at the end of the URL after asset-blobs/ for example 19950_en_1"?