# Cutting text from txt file before and after specific line

Tags: batch

So, my current code to get txt file with links form webpage is

```
@echo off

wget -m -p -E -k -K -np https://vk.com/XYZ/

rem    edit next line to include your filename    
set "zzfilename=.\vk.com\XYZ\index.html"

rem    get the target line
type "%zzfilename%"|find /i "https://m.vk.com/doc">"zztarget.txt"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`type "zztarget.txt"`) do set zzaaa=%%f

rem    change double-quotes to single-quotes
set "zzaaa1=%zzaaa:"='%"

rem    remove unneeded text from the beginning of the line
set "zzaaa2=%zzaaa1:*https://m.vk.com/doc=gotit%"

rem    remove the "<" and ">" characters
set "zzaaa3=%zzaaa2:<='%"
set "zzaaa4=%zzaaa3:>='%"

rem    from what remains, take only the desired URL
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims='" %%f in (`echo %zzaaa4%`) do set "zzgotit=%%f"

rem    show the work and cleanup
set zz
set "zzaaa="
set "zzaaa1="
set "zzaaa2="
set "zzaaa3="
set "zzaaa4="
del "zztarget.txt">nul 2>&1

pause
```

But the problem is now to **grab only links without any other text strings** and i don't know how to grab it, searched for it on forum but nothing works...
How should it be:

Links always start with

```
<a class="mr_label medias_link" href="
```

Links always end with

```
 " rel="noopener" target="_blank">
```

**What i want to do is to get new .txt file:**

BEFORE

```
 ... class="medias_link_icon"><i class="i_icon i_doc"></i></span><span class="medias_link_texts"><span class="medias_link_label">Plik</span><span class="medias_link_labeled medias_link_title"> </span><span class="medias_link_desc"> </span></span></a></div><div class="medias_row attachment_type_doc"><a class="mr_label medias_link" href="https://m.vk.com/doc16929061_546451452?hash=a33fc7d435c432a453&amp;dl=52261df6ba84d700f9" rel="noopener" target="_blank"> <span class="medias_link_icon"> class="medias_link_icon"><i class="i_icon i_doc"></i></span><span class="medias_link_texts"><span class="medias_link_label">Plik</span><span class="medias_link_labeled medias_link_title"> 2020-04-18_New_Scientist_UserUpload.Net.pdf</span><span class="medias_link_desc"> </span></span></a></div><div class="medias_row attachment_type_doc"><a class="mr_label medias_link" href="https://m.vk.com/doc16929061_546451452?hash=a33fc7d435c432a453&amp;dl=52261df6ba84d700f9" rel="noopener" target="_blank"> <span class="medias_link_icon"> ...
```

AFTER:

```
https://m.vk.com/doc116929061_546451452?hash=a33fc7d435c432a453&amp;dl=52261df6ba84d700f9
https://m.vk.com/doc116929061_546451485?hash=872bfbdaf4e0a2f015&amp;dl=52da751b3ad2c6b994
```

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
(Get-Content ".\vk.com\XYZ\index.html").split('"')|Select-String -SimpleMatch ";"
```

- Output:

```batch-file
https://m.vk.com/doc16929061_546451452?hash=a33fc7d435c432a453&amp;dl=52261df6ba84d700f9
```

You are may need some the answer options present in this **[question](https://superuser.com/questions/1537916/batch-script-to-find-a-string-in-a-messy-file-and-loop-until-all-strings-found/1540584#1540584)**:

In your specific case:

**1)** Split all **`"`** in your string:

```batch-file
...medias_link" href="https://m.vk.com/doc16929061_546451452?hash=a33fc7d435c432a453&dl=52261df6ba84d700f9" rel="noopener"....
```

**2)** Select the desired string by filtering the one that matches the character **"`;`"**

**Obs.:1)**
 Edit for to use your full path/relative path in:

```batch-file
Get-Content "D:\downloads\vk.com\XYZ\index.html"
Get-Content "..\vk.com\XYZ\index.html"
Get-Content ".\vk.com\XYZ\index.html"
```

**Obs.:2)** You can also use aliases **`gc|sls`**:

```batch-file
(gc ".\vk.com\XYZ\index.html").split('"')|sls -SimpleMatch ";"
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Split](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)**

  [√] **[Select-String | slc](https://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html)**

  [√] **[Get-Content | gc | cat](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)**